# Sum up drop down lists in Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, sum, sumifs

I have 4 drop down lists in Excel with the possible choice of either Yes or No as the two options. I also have conditional formatting too which makes a nice red/green colour.

I need a way to cout how many of the boxes have been set to Yes, I have tried `=SUMIF(A1:A4, "Yes")` but this hasn't worked. I will include a screenshot of my simple worksheet.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use countif

=COUNTIF(A:A,"yes")